System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.Elelement(…) returned null
I am reading .kml files saved out of Google Earth Pro.
Here is the code which I got from a post here on SO.  Works great when the xDoc.Descendants have consistent elements.
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    XNamespace ns = "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2";

    var placemarks = xDoc.Descendants(ns + "Placemark").Select(p => new
        {
             Name = (string)p.Element(ns + "name").Value.ToString(),
             Coords = p.Element(ns + "Point").Element(ns + "coordinates").Value,
        })
        .ToArray();

This will produce this with the below kml data
image of form displaying the read KML elements
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document id="1Y-yAHoHb_KrjsRT70KM5qLdZQjN_xcKW">
    <name>Test kml</name>
    <Placemark id="0B2FCD3E802CFEB8E9AD">
        <name>0+00 cabinet location 12’ BOC</name>
        <LookAt>
            <longitude>-93.28687708665021</longitude>
            <latitude>44.84264135896755</latitude>
            <altitude>255.3402528075096</altitude>
            <heading>0</heading>
            <tilt>0</tilt>
            <range>36.48488765818456</range>
            <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
            <gx:fovy>35</gx:fovy>
        </LookAt>
        <styleUrl>#msn_parking_lot</styleUrl>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-93.28687708665021,44.84264135896755,255.3402528075096</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>Place HH</name>
        <LookAt>
            <longitude>-93.28692035131073</longitude>
            <latitude>44.84255178413457</latitude>
            <altitude>0</altitude>
            <heading>1.868100177527735e-05</heading>
            <tilt>15.19185305855737</tilt>
            <range>106.8343470069538</range>
            <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
        </LookAt>
        <styleUrl>#msn_square0</styleUrl>
        <Point>
            <gx:drawOrder>1</gx:drawOrder>
            <coordinates>-93.28690200178055,44.84263978936539,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark id="0C6BEBC5352CFEBCA94D">
        <name>0+45 sewer</name>
        <LookAt>
            <longitude>-93.28845935397412</longitude>
            <latitude>44.84257694352023</latitude>
            <altitude>251.8505380949421</altitude>
            <heading>0</heading>
            <tilt>0</tilt>
            <range>63.54447705992244</range>
            <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
            <gx:fovy>35</gx:fovy>
        </LookAt>
        <styleUrl>#__managed_style_397C1C0EAA2D00EDBB6D</styleUrl>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-93.28845935397412,44.84257694352023,251.8505380949421</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>


But when the KML xDoc.Descendants have inconsistent elements such as the below KML, I get the System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.Elelement(…) returned null error because the first placemark does not have the point element.
image of error in visual studio
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document id="1Y-yAHoHb_KrjsRT70KM5qLdZQjN_xcKW">
    <name>Test KML</name>
    <Placemark>
        <name>Running line</name>
        <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        <LineString>
            <tessellate>1</tessellate>
            <coordinates>
                -93.28762387862635,44.84811886228031,0 -93.28753369589279,44.84814969351044,0 -93.28751831971846,44.84825957026099,0 -93.28749752003094,44.84895772192719,0 
            </coordinates>
        </LineString>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>Place HH</name>
        <LookAt>
            <longitude>-93.28692035131073</longitude>
            <latitude>44.84255178413457</latitude>
            <altitude>0</altitude>
            <heading>1.868100177527735e-05</heading>
            <tilt>15.19185305855737</tilt>
            <range>106.8343470069538</range>
            <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
        </LookAt>
        <styleUrl>#msn_square0</styleUrl>
        <Point>
            <gx:drawOrder>1</gx:drawOrder>
            <coordinates>-93.28690200178055,44.84263978936539,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark id="0C6BEBC5352CFEBCA94D">
        <name>0+45 sewer</name>
        <LookAt>
            <longitude>-93.28845935397412</longitude>
            <latitude>44.84257694352023</latitude>
            <altitude>251.8505380949421</altitude>
            <heading>0</heading>
            <tilt>0</tilt>
            <range>63.54447705992244</range>
            <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
            <gx:fovy>35</gx:fovy>
        </LookAt>
        <styleUrl>#__managed_style_397C1C0EAA2D00EDBB6D</styleUrl>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-93.28845935397412,44.84257694352023,251.8505380949421</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>


Is there are way to use this style of linq select and handle inconsistent elements?
Ultimately, I want it to get the coords out of the linestring /coordinates element when the placemark has them there, and the coords out of the Point/coordinate element when they are there. Can I have multiple array values populated with the value or null based on the "child" elements without null errors?  I can then deal with looking at nulls vs values.
If there are no coords in either point or linestring, both will just be null and I will deal with that.

Please provide a [mcve] rather than just snippets. In particular, a complete XML file would show the namespace that's being used - at the moment we just can't tell what namespace the Placemark element is actually in.

They don't need to be your full files - a minimal example that reproduces the problem is what I'm looking for...

@ Jon Skeet I have posted the entire KML file contents instead of just the placemark descendants.

Right, that's a bit better. I can reproduce the problem. But you haven't said what you want to happen for a Placemark element with no Point child. Should Coords be null? Or an empty string? Or something else?

Just changing the Coords part to Coords = p.Element(ns + "Point")?.Element(ns + "coordinates")?.Value gives a null value and no errors...

Ultimately, I want it to get the coords out of the linestring coordinates when they are there and the coords out of the Point when they are like that.  Can I have both and just have the one populated and the other not based on the "child" elements.

Let me elaborate on the end goal in the question.

You can always call LINQ Where before Select and eliminate items that don't have data you need

@T.S.: That won't give the requested results though. It would stop the errors, but it's pretty easy to give the results requested in the question.


Is there are way to use this style of linq select and handle inconsistent elements?

Absolutely - you just need to stop unconditionally dereferencing something that can be null. Using the null-conditional operator and the null-coalescing operator, this is quite straightforward:
var placemarks = xDoc
    .Descendants(ns + "Placemark")
    .Select(p => new
{
    Name = p.Element(ns + "name").Value,
    Coords = (p.Element(ns + "LineString")?.Element(ns + "coordinates").Value)
       ?? (p.Element(ns + "Point")?.Element(ns + "coordinates").Value)
});

The brackets there aren't strictly necessary, but I think they make it easier to see what's going on. Note that this will still fail if there's a LineString or Point element without a coordinates child. You can use more null-conditional operators (before Value) to avoid that:
var placemarks = xDoc
    .Descendants(ns + "Placemark")
    .Select(p => new
{
    Name = p.Element(ns + "name").Value,
    Coords = (p.Element(ns + "LineString")?.Element(ns + "coordinates")?.Value)
       ?? (p.Element(ns + "Point")?.Element(ns + "coordinates")?.Value)
});

(I've removed the cast and the ToString call for Name, as they weren't necessary - XElement.Value already returns a string.)
